# Mysql: using regexp matches as fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I read the [mysql documentation about regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) but looks like the regexp **can be used only as `WHERE` filters** to match rows in `SELECT` query.

Im wondering if is possible to extract the matches of the regexp as columns, for example if in my table i have a SKU textfield with:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
|sku             | product_name | [other fields]|
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
|ART-2830--107-70| Foo          |               |
|ART-2832--115-6 | Bar          |               |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

it would be great to fire a select query that matches the regexp `(ART-)([0-9]+)(--)([0-9]+)(-)([0-9]+)` that gives me as output:

```
+------+------------+-------+----------+
| type | collection | model | material |
+------+------------+-------+----------+
| ART  | 2830       | 107   | 70       |
| ART  | 2832       | 115   | 6        |
+------+------------+-------+----------+
```

Please note that `type, collection, model and material` columns are not present into my table, and are merely the matches of the regexp above.

Is this possible?

p.s: I know that would be a GREAT idea to normalize that table adding a column for each *property* i need, but this is the structure I have to work with and I can not edit this at the moment.

**EDIT** Just in case someone need this, I saw that [PostgreSql offer this function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "no" in general -- at least not without a lot of brute force coding.  But, you are lucky, because you can do what you want "easily" in MySQL:

```
select substring_index(sku, '-', 1) as type,
       reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(sku, '-', 2)), '-', 1)) as collection,
       reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(sku, '-', 4)), '-', 1)) as model,
       reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(sku, '-', 5)), '-', 1)) as material
from skus
```

Ok, perhaps not the most obvious collection of functions.  But here is what it does for model:

Start with:    `ART-2830--107-70`

```
substring_index(sku, '-', 4) --> ART-2830--107
```

The `reverse()`:

701--0381-TRA

The outer `substring_index( . . . 1)`:

```
701
```

And the final `reverse()`:

```
107
```

Comment: So sad this is the only way.. At this point, is much better grab the data from db using the regexp to match the rows and then process the result server side. If I only could create another table to normalize the data..

Answer (score 0):

Using regex in a select statement is really dependent on the sql language. For MySql you can read some more on it in the manual.

This section of the manual talks about using a regex select statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html. That manual page also has the following link to examples of how to use regex statements for where statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

This example is also in the manual.

```
To find names containing a “w”, use this query:

mysql> SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name REGEXP 'w';
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name     | owner | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Claws    | Gwen  | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
| Bowser   | Diane | dog     | m    | 1989-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
| Whistler | Gwen  | bird    | NULL | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
+----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
```

---

**can you return data based on regex capture groups?**

No. The where statement filters the data being returned by the SQL engine. You would need to build an entry for each column of data you'd like returned. As in Gordon Linoff's answer each column could be processed by SQL to manually extract data from a given column. But this solution is far from the rosy ideal of using a regex to describe a sql select statement.

I you intend on using regex capture groups to extract data then this would need to be done after you receive the data.

Comment: The first row of my question tell _I read the mysql documentation about regexp but looks like the regexp can be used as WHERE filters to match rows in SELECT query._

Did you skip that part?

Comment: Updated the answer to show exactly where in the MySql manual it talks about how to use a regexp as WHERE filters to match rows in SELECT query.

Comment: Sorry mate, I dont want to look rude, but if you read my question you'll see that your answer is not related.. im not asking _how to use regexp in mysql_ but **how to use the matches of a regexp as columns**
  I guess is a misunderstanding ;)
let me update my question to clarify this

Comment: Updated answer to cover the exact question: how to use a regex capture group to define the columns of data that are returned from a select statement.